# Parent Child List Layout

Tags: list

I have a Parent/Child list setup but not sure how to change the display of it.

[image]

How do I modify how the data is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, That might not be possible Out of the box. However you can try JSLink to change the look to the desired format. You can check the samples here : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Comment: OK. Might be a little over my head as I didn't see anything specific to apply. I'm surprised there's not a way to just add a break in the results.